# UISCcrollView's contentSize changes after keyboard appears

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

Basing on:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

I have implemented a feature that scrolls the view automatically whenever keyboard hides selected text input (mine and the one from tutorial are actually the same).

Unfortunately, there is an undesirable behaviour: my scrollView's `contentSize` property gets increased by the height of the keyboard. So when keyboard is still visible I can scroll the view, but below proper content a blank space appears. This is a thing I would like to avoid. I'm aware this is caused by changing `contentInset` property, so maybe there is another way to do this thing without side-effects.

At first I register observers for `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`:

```
- (void)registerKeyboardNotifications
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

this function is called in `viewWillAppear`. Methods `keyboardWasShown` and `keyboardWillBeHidden` look as following:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
    rect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if(!CGRectContainsPoint(rect, activeField.frame.origin)) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 2*activeField.frame.size.height+activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
        [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
 }

 - (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification *)notification
 {
     UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
     scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
     scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
 }
```

As I wrote earlier, it is basically Apple's solution.

Comment: It would be good to post some relevant code snippets here, such as the keyboard notification responder methods.

Comment: Why do you use the contentInsets there? Did you add this to overcome your problem?

Comment: No. I just took Apple's code and I wasn't aware of any side effects. I'm quite new to iOS.

Comment: Allright, you have taken this (contenInsects) from Apple's solution. I'll have a closer look at that. (I've got a similar problem but the otehr way around. My scroll view content view is too small.)

Comment: I believe it is about contentInsets. I just turned off setting scorllView's contentInsets and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Content inset is meant to allow access to parts of the scroll view that might appear hidden below keyboard (for example). So if you had a text view on the bottom of your content, the user would not be able to interact with it, as it would be hidden beneath the keyboard window. With content inset (as per the Apple example), you are able to scroll it more, and reveal the text view. It doesn't actually increase the `contentSize` property.

Please read more here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html

Answer (score 0):

```
CGFloat contentSizeHeight = contentSize.height;
CGFloat collectionViewFrameHeight = self.collectionView.frame.size.height;
CGFloat collectionViewBottomInset = self.collectionView.contentInset.bottom;
CGFloat collectionViewTopInset = self.collectionView.contentInset.top;
CGPoint bottomOffsetForContentSize = CGPointMake(0, MAX(-collectionViewTopInset, contentSizeHeight - (collectionViewFrameHeight - collectionViewBottomInset)));
[self.collectionView setContentOffset:bottomOffsetForContentSize animated:animated];
```

Comment: Thank you for offering an answer to rader of StackOverflow. However, it is normal to offer some description of why your code is a better solution that the others. Can you edit this answer and add some descriptive text? 谢谢